# DataGrid to Excel?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a program created in WPF. It displays a `DataGrid` with data from a MySQL Database. What I want to do is to allow the user to export the contents of the `DataGrid` to an Excel file. Is this possible with WPF?

When I use the method shown here: https://www.outcoldman.ru/en/blog/show/201

The only row that gets imported to the xls file is the header.

Comment: It would be great if you could happen to accept the answer that helped you the most so that another member can quickly see what might be his solution either. Thanks for your attention, Nath! =)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was also looking for something simillar to help export the data in the datagrid into excel, but found nothing which works.
Atlast I just converted the content of the DataGrid into a 2D array of string and exported it using the interop dll.

The code looks something like this:

```
    Excel.Application xlApp;
    Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
    Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
    object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
    Excel.Range rangeToHoldHyperlink;
    Excel.Range CellInstance;
    xlApp = new Excel.Application();
    xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue);

    xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
    xlApp.DisplayAlerts = false;
    //Dummy initialisation to prevent errors.
    rangeToHoldHyperlink = xlWorkSheet.get_Range("A1", Type.Missing);
    CellInstance = xlWorkSheet.get_Range("A1", Type.Missing);

    for (int i = 0; i < NumberOfCols; i++)
    {
            for (int j = 0; j <= NumberOfRows; j++)
            {
                xlWorkSheet.Cells[j + 1, i + 1] = DataToWrite[j][i];
            }
     }
```

If you are looking for some formating, they are also supported in this. I wanted to add a hyperlink and the following code does that:

```
 CellInstance = xlWorkSheet.Cells[j + 1, i + 1];

                xlWorkSheet.Hyperlinks.Add(
                    CellInstance,
                    DataToWrite[j][i],
                    Type.Missing,
                    "Hover Text Comes Here",
                    "Text to be displayed");
```

If you want the first row to be the header, you can highlight them as follows:

```
Excel.Range Range1 = xlWorkSheet.get_Range("A1");
Range1.EntireRow.Font.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Black);
Range1.EntireRow.Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.LightSkyBlue);
Range1.EntireRow.Font.Size = 14;
Range1.EntireRow.AutoFit();
```

Finally to Save the excel in a desired path:

```
xlWorkBook.SaveAs(@FilePath, Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
xlWorkBook.Close();
```

The reference to the interop is added as follows:

```
Right Click on the Project name -> Click "Add reference" -> Goto "COM" tab -> Search for "Microsoft Excel Object Library" click "OK" to add the reference.
```

You must be using the following namespace :

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
```

Comment: How to I get number of columns and rows in WPF?

Comment: The number of rows and cols depend upon the size of your 2D string - in this case the DataToWrite.

Comment: I'm still figuring out how to get the number of rows and columns of the datagrid.

Comment: In my case the datagrid is bound to a observable collection of a particular object. I had a method as part of the object which would return the required content in the form of an array and I could build a 2D array out of all the objects in the collection. Not the most elegant solution, but it worked. Rather than getting the data from the datagrid, try to get it from the source of data (in my case the object to which it was binded).

Comment: How do I convert DataGrid to 2d Array?

Comment: If you are using WPF, data binding is the most common method of getting data into the front panel(the user interface). That gives you a lot of flexibility - you basically use MVVM pattern. See the first two line of Will Marcouiller code in the answer. That is an example of data binding. You could post the code you are using to get data into the grid here.

Comment: I use this   grid.ItemsSource = schedList.DefaultView;

Comment: Is schedList of type DataTable? I have not worked with DataTable, but extracting data from schedList must be the way to go. Try to find if you can get individual rows or cols out of schedList. A quick google search threw up the following link : http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/zh/winformsdatacontrols/thread/00030777-82cc-40d7-811d-d35c5e8826a3

Comment: Yes, it is a DataTable. Thank you

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9257/discussion-between-nath-and-manoj)

Answer (score 2):

You could also export your DataGrid content into a CSV file.

I don't know if you're using data binding, and here I am assuming you do.

```
var items = LoadItemsFromUnderlyingDataStore();
itemsDataGrid.ItemsSource = items;

private void ItemsDataGridExportButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    var filename = AutoGenerateDateTimedFileName();
    using (var csv = new FileStream(filename)) {
        // if you want any column header in your Excel file, uncomment line below.            
        //csv.WriteLine("Column1,Column2,Column3,Column4");
        items.ForEach(item => 
            csv.WriteLine("{0},{1},{2},{3}"
                , item.PropertyFromFirstColumn
                , item.PropertyFromSecondColumn
                , item.PropertyFromThirdColumn
                , item.PropertyFromFourthColumn);
        try { csv.Flush(); }
        catch(IOException ex) { 
            // Handle error (log, whatever...)
            throw; // If you need to let the exception bubble up...
        }
    }
}

private string AutoGenerateDateTimedFileName() {
    return string.Format("DataGridExport_{0}_{1}.csv"
        , DataTime.Today.ToShortDateString()
        , DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());
}
```

In summary, this code sample should do it with CSV files, and you're able to open it using Excel afterwards. You could even launch Excel upon file creation.

```
private void ItemsDataGridExportButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    // here's the upper code sample, and add the following:
    Process.Start(filename)
}
```

Now, using the Excel Interop.

```
object[,] values = BuildTwoDimensionalMatrixFromDataGridContent();
Worksheet.Cells.Value(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlRangeValueDataType.xlRangeValueDefault) = values;
```

This is probably the fastest way to set values within an Excel file and there is no iteration to address.

The first proposed solution using a CSV file is probably the easiest to understand and work with.

> Disclaimer
>
> *This code was created right from the top of my head and as such has not been tested. Some changes might be required for this code to work properly with your program's context. Furthermore, there might be a need for slight differences analysis between the code with the interop shown here and the one you'll be able to use with WPF.*

The best way is perhaps by writing yourself a class library which shall be deployed with your solution that would be written in plain C# so that you could use simple Interop instructions.

Answer (score 1):

This link could be useful to you-

[Export data to Excel from Silverlight/WPF DataGrid](https://www.outcoldman.com/en/blog/show/201)

Comment: That link could be very useful, but a link by itself doesn't make a good answer. You should take some relevant excerpts from it and quote them here. What happens to your answer if there is link rot (the target page disappears)?

Comment: It's a great article and I was able to apply the methods the author used. Unfortunately, when I try to export, the only row that gets exported is the field names and everything is blank.

Answer (score 0):

The example code retrieves list of all directories from *C:\Windows\WinSxS*, binds it to DataGrid and exports DataGrid to Excel. The core thing here is to know that the fastest way to export data to Excel is assigning array to worksheet. But the problem is we can't get this array directly from DataGrid. Thus, we first need to fill it. Using a bit of reflection, we can get the properties values and fill array up. The exporting data is one line at all. The WinSxS folder on my computer contains 14880 directories. The code runs for about 3 seconds (filling DataGrid + export).

```
    using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

    private void ExportDataGrid()
    {
        // Fetch directories
        var dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Windows\WinSxS\");
        var items = dirInfo.EnumerateDirectories();
        dataGrid.ItemsSource = items;
        var source = dataGrid.ItemsSource;

        // Create Excel app
        var excel = new Excel.Application { Visible = true };
        excel.ScreenUpdating = false; //Some speed-up
        var book = excel.Workbooks.Add();
        var sheet = (Excel.Worksheet)book.Sheets[1];

        int row = -1; //The row in array
        Type type = null;

        // Create array to hold data
        int rows = items.Count(), cols = dataGrid.Columns.Count;
        var arr = new object[rows, cols];

        foreach (DirectoryInfo dir_info in dataGrid.ItemsSource)
        {
            ++row;
            // You can also use GetType().GetTypeInfo() as of .NET 4.5+.
            // The return type will be TypeInfo.
            type = dir_info.GetType();
            for (int col = 0; col < cols; ++col)
            {
                var column_name = (string)dataGrid.Columns[col].Header;
                var value = type.GetProperty(column_name).GetValue(dir_info);
                arr.SetValue(value, row, col);
            }
        }

        // Create header
        for (int col = 0; c < cols; ++c)
        {
            sheet.Cells[1, col + 1].Value = dataGrid.Columns[col].Header;
        }

        // Dump array - the fastest way
        sheet.Range["A2"].Resize[rows, cols].Value = arr;

        // Restore screen updating - otherwise Excel will not response to actions
        excel.ScreenUpdating = true;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void data2Exel(DataGrid dataGrid)
        {
            Excel.Application excel = new Excel.Application();
            excel.Visible = true; //www.yazilimkodlama.com
            Workbook workbook = excel.Workbooks.Add(System.Reflection.Missing.Value);
            Worksheet sheet1 = (Worksheet)workbook.Sheets[1];

            for (int j = 0; j < dataGrid.Columns.Count; j++) //Başlıklar için
            {
                Range myRange = (Range)sheet1.Cells[1, j + 1];
                sheet1.Cells[1, j + 1].Font.Bold = true; //Başlığın Kalın olması için
                sheet1.Columns[j + 1].ColumnWidth = 15; //Sütun genişliği ayarı
                myRange.Value2 = dataGrid.Columns[j].Header;
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < dataGrid.Columns.Count; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < dataGrid.Items.Count; j++)
                {
                    TextBlock b = dataGrid.Columns[i].GetCellContent(dataGrid.Items[j]) as TextBlock;
                    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range myRange = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)sheet1.Cells[j + 2, i + 1];
                    myRange.Value2 = b.Text;
                }
            }
        }
```